# Data indicators monitoring wtih workbooks in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, monitoring

I know that there is a 'subscription' function offered by tableau online but I am just wonder if there are any other methods to monitor data indicators displayed in views or workbooks through extracting or crawling data from tableau.

Comment: What indicators are your looking to pull?

Comment: which have already been calculated and displayed in workbooks